# Backward compatibility for plugins

Tags: compatibility

Are plugins normally backward comatible? I would like to buy a plugin ready for Mathematica 7 and use it on Mathematica 8.

Comment: It depends on the particular plugin. Check with the plugin's author or publisher.

Answer (score 2):

I would say no. I know of one counter example: [Link for Excel](http://www.wolfram.com/products/applications/excel_link/). When Mathematica 9 came out it wasn't compatible (see the comments below [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23864/5485)), but it has since been updated. If you want to be sure, contact the creators of the plugin (or package) before buying.