# Run Mathematica notebook using VBA

Tags: interoperability, excel, excellink

I want to run mathematica notebook using excel vba, can someone help me with a sample code?

Comment: This is sort of a duplicate https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23864/mathematica-functions-from-vba except I couldn't get the other code to work when I tried it last.

Comment: Are you trying to get results back into Excel or do you just want to initiate a  notebook evaluation from Excel VBA?

Comment: I want to initiate notebook evaluation from using vba